# SmtpClient sending duplicate message

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtpclient

Every time I send an email using the SmtpClient I always receive emails? Cannot see why at all? Please help thanks.

From my controller :

```
foreach(var reciever in notifications.ToList() ) {

    var msg = new MailMessage();
    mail.To.Add(to);
    mail.From = new MailAddress("notifications@someone.com");
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.Body = body; // contains html email
    mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    //Add the Creddentials- use your own email id and password
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(MyConfig.SmtpLogin, MyConfig.SmtpPassword);

    client.Port = PlayCaddyMailerConfig.SmtpPort; // 587; // Gmail works on this port
    client.Host = PlayCaddyMailerConfig.SmtpServer; // "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true; //Gmail works on Server Secured Layer
    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exception ex2 = ex;
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        while (ex2 != null)
        {
            errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
            ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
        }

        throw ex2;
    } // end try    

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one item in that list? You are iterating over a list and sending an email once per item..

Comment: Not only are you in a loop... but you are not doing anything with `reciever`... so why loop. It does the same thing each iteration. (and it's spelled receiver)

Comment: You not use a receiver variable, you use a "to" varaible. Does not matter waht is in the receiver or what is in the list, you send all the mail for vontetnt "to".